# Python 3 - how to make mosaic plots from higher-dimensional data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plot

I have a pandas-DataFrame:

`data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\data-path\demographics.csv', sep=',')
 print(data)`

`PersonID  Married  No. of Children    Sex
        1     yes                0    male
        2      no                0  female
        3      no                1    male
        4     yes                1    male
        5      no                1  female
        6      no                2  female
        7      no                1    male
        8      no                2    male
        9      no                2    male
       10      no                1    male
       11      no                0  female`

Now I try to create a mosaicplot out of it, using [statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic.html)

`mosaic(data, ['Married', 'No. of Children'])`

...which works, however, whenever I try to add a third dimension, for example:

`mosaic(data, ['Married', 'No. of Children', 'Sex'])`

... I get the following error-message:

`ValueError: at least one proportion should begreater than zero`

I am not sure, what it wants from me. Is there some parameter missing/wrongly set?

It also doesn't matter which columns/dimensions I choose, or in what order. Whenever I have more than 2, I get an error.

Anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Upon further reasearch I have encountered the following: http://photo.etangkk.com/Python/blog-03.asp. Near the bottom of the page, there is also a mosaic plotting of 3 variables. I tried the code myself, and it indeed works! What is the big difference between her and my code? Her data is actually alot more complex than mine... Anybody have an idea of what's going on here?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352585/how-to-make-a-mosaic-plot-in-matplotlib) for another approach

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering I didn't find the solution but the origin of the bug.

It lies within the code of the mosaicplot-class/-module: http://nipy.bic.berkeley.edu/nightly/statsmodels/doc/html/_modules/statsmodels/graphics/mosaicplot.html

In short: It is unable to handle classes in a dataset, which are empty, i.e. have 0 instances.

Consider the dataset from the original question and then the following function call:

`mosaic(data, ['Married', 'No. of Children'])`

What the 'mosaic'-method will do, is to determine how many classes the first category has (in this case: 2), and then how often each of the classes occurs. It will then generate a list of 'Proportions' for the plot's rectangles based on that, which in case of the 'Married'-category will be

[2, 9]

...as there are 2 'yes' and 9 'no' instances.

For each of the classes, there will be new splits, according to the second category, here: 'No. of Children'. There are 3 classes (0, 1, and 2) and this will generate the folloing 'proportions':

[1, 1, 0] (1 married with 0 children, 1 married with 1 child, 0 married with 2 children)

[2, 4, 3] ( 1 single with 0 children, etc....)

Based on the above alone, it is able to draw a perfectly fine mosaic plot.

However, once we take a third category into account (for instance: 'Sex'), the 0 in one of the lists above becomes a problem. It will spawn the list [0, 0] as they are 0 married men/women with 2 children.

And in line 45 of the source code, there is an if-clause that will raise the exception at all-0-lists (as they are 'not meaningful').

As said above, I was not able to find a fix/workaround to do this. Simply out-commenting said if-clause will allow all the splits to be performed normally, however, this will also cause the drawing of the mosaic-plot to throw an exception in matplotlib's backend_agg.py, as somehow they are now values which are NaN (not a number).

Why this is, I have no idea, and I would be glad if someone brighter and more experienced than me would look into this.

I still won't rule out that I have just have to set some parameters differently.