# How to make a mosaic plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I know that you can use the [mosaic plot from statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic.html) but it is a bit frustrating when your categories have some empty values ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987423/python-3-how-to-make-mosaic-plots-from-higher-dimensional-data)). I was wondering whether it exists a solution with a graphic library like matplotlib or seaborn, which would be more handy.

I think it would be a nice feature for seaborn, as contingency tables are frequently built with pandas. However it seems that [it won't be implemented](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1016#issuecomment-247853671) anytime soon.

Finally, how to have a mosaic plot with 3 dimensions, and possible empty categories ?

Here is a generic mosaic plot (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot))
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As nothing existed in python, here is the code I made. The last dimension should be of size 1 (i.e. a regular table) or 2 for now. Feel free to update the code to fix that, it might be unreadable with more than 3, though. 
It's a bit long but it does the job. Example below.

There are few options, most are self explanatory, otherwise:

- `dic_color_row`: a dictionary where keys are the outer-most index (`Index_1` in example below) and the values are colors, avoid black/gray colors
- `pad`: the space between each bar of the plot
- `alpha_label`: the 3rd dimension use alpha trick to differentiate, between them, it will be rendered as dark grey / light grey in the legend and you can change the name of each label (similar to `col_labels` or `row_labels`)
- `color_label`: to add background color to the y-tick labels. [True/False]

  ```
  def mosaic_plot(df, dic_color_row, row_labels=None, col_labels=None, alpha_label=None, top_label="Size",
                  x_label=None, y_label=None, pad=0.01, color_ylabel=False, ax=None, order="Size"):
      """ 

      From a contingency table NxM, plot a mosaic plot with the values inside. There should be a double-index for rows
      e.g.
                                           3   4   1   0   2  5
          Index_1          Index_2                       
          AA               C               0   0   0   2   3  0
                           P               6   0   0  13   0  0
          BB               C               0   2   0   0   0  0
                           P              45   1  10  10   1  0
          CC               C               0   6  35  15  29  0
                           P               1   1   0   2   0  0
          DD               C               0  56   0   3   0  0
                           P              30   4   2   0   1  9

      order: how columns are order, by default, from the biggest to the smallest in term of category. Possible values are 
          - "Size" [default]
          - "Normal" : as the columns are order in the input df
          - list of column names to reorder the column
      top_label: Size of each columns. The label can be changed to adapt to your value. 
                 If `False`, nothing is displayed and the secondary legend is set on top instead of on right.  
      """

      is_multi = len(df.index.names) == 2
      if ax == None:
          fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(len(df.columns), len(df.index.get_level_values(0).unique())))

      size_col = df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
      prop_com = size_col.div(size_col.sum())

      if order == "Size":
          df = df[size_col.index.values]
      elif order == "Normal":
          prop_com = prop_com[df.columns]
          size_col = size_col[df.columns]
      else:
          df = df[order]
          prop_com = prop_com[order]
          size_col = size_col[order]

      if is_multi:
          inner_index = df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()
          prop_ii0 = (df.swaplevel().loc[inner_index[0]]/(df.swaplevel().loc[inner_index[0]]+df.swaplevel().loc[inner_index[1]])).fillna(0)
          alpha_ii = 0.5
          true_y_labels = df.index.levels[0]
      else:
          alpha_ii = 1
          true_y_labels = df.index

      Yt = (df.groupby(level=0).sum().iloc[:,0].div(df.groupby(level=0).sum().iloc[:,0].sum())+pad).cumsum() - pad
      Ytt = df.groupby(level=0).sum().iloc[:,0].div(df.groupby(level=0).sum().iloc[:,0].sum())

      x = 0    
      for j in df.groupby(level=0).sum().iteritems():
          bot = 0
          S = float(j[1].sum())
          for lab, k in j[1].iteritems():
              bars = []
              ax.bar(x, k/S, width=prop_com[j[0]], bottom=bot, color=dic_color_row[lab], alpha=alpha_ii, lw=0, align="edge")
              if is_multi:
                  ax.bar(x, k/S, width=prop_com[j[0]]*prop_ii0.loc[lab, j[0]], bottom=bot, color=dic_color_row[lab], lw=0, alpha=1, align="edge")
              bot += k/S + pad
          x += prop_com[j[0]] + pad

      ## Aesthetic of the plot and ticks
      # Y-axis
      if row_labels == None:
          row_labels = Yt.index
      ax.set_yticks(Yt - Ytt/2)
      ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels)

      ax.set_ylim(0, 1 + (len(j[1]) - 1) * pad)
      if y_label == None:
          y_label = df.index.names[0]
      ax.set_ylabel(y_label)

      # X-axis
      if col_labels == None:
          col_labels = prop_com.index
      xticks = (prop_com + pad).cumsum() - pad - prop_com/2.
      ax.set_xticks(xticks)
      ax.set_xticklabels(col_labels)
      ax.set_xlim(0, prop_com.sum() + pad * (len(prop_com)-1))

      if x_label == None:
          x_label = df.columns.name
      ax.set_xlabel(x_label)

      # Top label
      if top_label:
          ax2 = ax.twiny()
          ax2.set_xlim(*ax.get_xlim())
          ax2.set_xticks(xticks) 
          ax2.set_xticklabels(size_col.values.astype(int))
          ax2.set_xlabel(top_label)
          ax2.tick_params(top=False, right=False, pad=0, length=0)

      # Ticks and axis settings

      ax.tick_params(top=False, right=False, pad=5)
      sns.despine(left=0, bottom=False, right=0, top=0, offset=3)

      # Legend
      if is_multi: 
          if alpha_label == None:
              alpha_label = inner_index
          bars = [ax.bar(np.nan, np.nan, color="0.2", alpha=[1, 0.5][b]) for b in range(2)]
          if top_label:
              plt.legend(bars, alpha_label, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), ncol=1, )
          else:
              plt.legend(bars, alpha_label, loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1), ncol=2)
      plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, .9, 0.95])
      if color_ylabel:
          for tick, label in zip(ax.get_yticklabels(), true_y_labels):
              tick.set_bbox(dict( pad=5, facecolor=dic_color_row[label]))
              tick.set_color("w")
              tick.set_fontweight("bold")

      return ax
  ```

With a dataframe you get after a crosstabulation:

```
df
Index_1          Index_2         v   w   x   y   z
AA               Q               0   0   0   2   3 
AA               P               6   0   0  13   0
BB               Q               0   2   0   0   0
BB               P              45   1  10  10   1
CC               Q               0   6   0  15   9
CC               P               0   1   0   2   0
DD               Q               0  56   0   3   0
DD               P              30   4   2   0   1
```

make sure that you have the 2 columns as index:

```
df.set_index(["Index_1", "Index_2"], inplace=True)
```

and then just call:

```
mosaic_plot(df,
           {"AA":"r", "BB":"b", "CC":"y", "DD":"g"}, # dict of color, mandatory
           x_label='My Category', 
           )
```

It's not perfect, but I hope it will help others. 
[image: mosaicplot python]

Comment: This looks great - the statsmodel implementation is a bit limiting. However, I can't quite get it to work: should `prop_ii0 = (df.swaplevel()...` be `prop_ii0 = (df.swaplevel(0,1)...` ? And if so, presumably the other swap levels. I can't quite work out what this bit does though!

Comment: Also, would it be possible to label each rectangle with a value?

Comment: @TMrtSmith You can totally add a few lines to annotate the rectangle with `plt.text()` as you know the position of the rectangle and the values. I did not get your first question; both `df.swaplevel()` and `df.swaplevel(0,1)` are identical operation.